# Does embedRelation() (sfPropel15Plugin) works for many-to-many relationships?

Tags: symfony1, propel

does embedRelation() (sfPropel15Plugin) works for many-to-many
relationships? If not any experience or tutorial to get that (embed
forms for m:m relations)?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1):

schema.yml

```
product:
    id:           ~
    name:         {type: varchar(255), required: true}
    price:        {type: integer, required: true}

  order_list:
    id:           ~
    order_id:     {type: integer, required: true, foreignTable: order, foreignReference: id, onDelete: cascade, onUpdate: cascade}
    product_id:   {type: integer, required: true, foreignTable: product, foreignReference: id, onDelete: cascade, onUpdate: cascade}

  order:
    id:           ~
    name:         {type: varchar(255), required: true}
```

Class form:

```
class OrderForm extends BaseOrderForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
      $this->embedRelation('OrderList');
  }
}
```

Add it look like:

[image]